# Angular JS/UI-Router: disable directives for a given state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular 1.3 app using UI router.  I have a view for the pages and a directive for the header and another for the footer.

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

<!-- header -->
<div header></div>

<!-- content -->
<div ui-view=""></div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div footer></div>
```

There are some states in my app where I do not want to display the header and/or footer.  How is that done?

Comment: use `ng-hide` or `ng-show` and set visibility from controllers

Answer (score 1):

Implement a method in your controller that decides whether the header should be visible for a given state, e.g.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
    this.isHeaderVisible = function() {
        return ...// your logic here
    }
});
```

And then use `ng-if` (or `ng-show` as per the comment):

```
<div header ng-if="app.isHeaderVisible()"></div>
```

Same goes for footer.

Comment: Not working for some reason.  In my page controller I have the function, which returns `true`.  Then, in the directive I have `<div header ng-hide="hideHeaderFooter()"></div>`.  Although a console log confirms the function returns true, the header still shows.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code; it is some small detail you have missed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ng-hide or controllers. Ui-router has a built in functionallity to do so. Use nested states and nested views to show/hide according to the state you are at the moment. 
Take a look at these links:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views.

Set up a plunker and I help you get it working.

Comment: Thanks.  I uploaded my router for a given section of my app. http://cl.ly/code/282o0U0t0o2P/elements.js  I can see how to add the new views (I added them to the parent state) except now I'm not sure how to re-integrate my original views to the main view `<div ui-view-"main"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using individual controllers for your states, you can set boolean scope variables in each and then use those and ng-show to control what's being shown.

Comment: This only seems to work with positives: `ng-if` and `ng-show`.  That would require me to add variables to every controller where it shows rather that setting only the one it's hidden on to false.  `ng-hide` seems not to work and setting a test like `ng-show="!hideHeaderFooter"` does not work.  Only thing that seems to work is `ng-show="showHeaderFooter"` which requires setting this true everywhere and false on the one screen.  Isn't there a way to just have the condition respond to the ONE controller/state?

Answer (score 0):

Use angular `ui-router` please!!!

It is a very nice style to organize your views:

Documentation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Examples: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

`Controllers + ng-hide` are not well to handle nested views because the DOM be too loaded. Thus, `ui-route` was developed to do it. Although `ng-hide` can be used do it, ui-route is even better.